# Integrate REST API in Wordpress

Tags: php, json, wordpress, rest

Currently I am trying to integrate an external REST API in a website for the company I am working for (https://www.chiptuningnoord.nl/)

We tune cars by adjusting the software. On our website we use NinjaTables Pro to show visitors how many HP a car can get after a modification. E.g. https://www.chiptuningnoord.nl/merken/audi-chiptunen/ (make a selection of all parameters). The information comes from a huge csv-file which takes an amount of time to load.

Desired solution: import data into the table from an external REST API. See this documentation: https://api.dyno-chiptuningfiles.com/documentation

The support from NinjaTables has not been enough for me. They only gave this specific piece of code:

```
<?php
/*
 * Say we want to change data of table id 1477 then you can write the following 
 * code.
 * $data is the array of frontend data
 */
add_filter('ninja_tables_get_public_data', function ($data, $tableId) {
    if ($tableId == 1477) {
        $data[] = [
            'name' => 'Dynaic Name',
            'email' => 'my@dyne.com',
            'phone' => '983129123123'
        ];
    }
    return $data;
}, 15, 2);
```

Anyone around here that can help me out with simple yet effective solution?

Kind regards,

Jefta Elachouri

Comment: Could you please provide us with the code that is currently used to show the frontend data from the csv?

Comment: There is no specific piece of code as it is a 3rd party plugin. Once in a while we upload a fresh csv-file into the NinjaTables Pro plugin. We want to get rid of that. Instead the table should load data from an external API.